# Meaning of "you don't owe me anything"

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-request, sentence-usage

What is the meaning of the sentences

> You don't owe me anything.
>
> I don't owe you anything.
>
> we don't owe each other anything.

Is there any other way of saying the same thing in English, but in a more native manner (way)? If yes, then please let me know.

Comment: You owe me nothing!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see what you find difficult about these, unless they are being used metaphorically, in which case you need to give us some context.

Literally, they mean that you/I/we have no debt: there is nothing (no money or services) which are owed.

I suspect that the use you are asking about is where there is not a formal debt but a possible social obligation, and they mean either "there is nothing I/you/we have done which incurs an obligation on you/me/us" or "There is such an obligation, but I am/you are/we are/ choosing to cancel that obligation"

In any case, these are perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The three examples that you quote can be used literally about money or favours: they can also be used about [relationships](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/maybe-its-just-me/201008/what-do-we-owe-our-partners-obligation-in-relationships).

A very idiomatic expression for the literal meaning "neither of us owes anything to the other" is

> We're quits

Here is a [reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quits)

Answer (score 0):

"There is not any amount unpaid or any obligation or promise withstanding and unfulfilled between us/ the parties"

I think this phrasing could be used in a legal document to express what you would like to say.

If you want, you can also add "we, hereby, state that"